# Get associated records using joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have Category, Book, Order Models

**Category.rb**

```
has_many :books
```

**Book.rb**

```
belongs_to :category
has_many :orders
```

**Order.rb**

```
belongs_to :book.
```

My task is get the orders got placed on specific category.

I've tried these two options:

**Using joins**

```
Order.joins(:book => :category).where('books.category_id = ?', 138)
```

**And using two queries:**

1. To find out book_ids which comes under a specific category
2. Find out orders which has those book_ids

   book_ids = Book.where(:category_id => 138).pluck(:id)

   Order.where(:book_id => book_ids).

I wondering which one is correct. How can I get the orders got placed on specific category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach looks correct and as if it should work. I'd tweak it to be a little more 'Railsy', as follows:

```
Order.joins(book: :category).where(books: { categories: { id: 138 } })
```

**Edit:** Actually, saying that, if you know your category ID in advance, you can skip loading the category at all, as follows:

```
Order.joins(:book).where(books: { category_id: 138 })
```

This will be much more efficient than the second approach as Rails will optimise the database query, while you won't have to store the book ids in memory then have a second transaction.

If you would like to access attributes of an order's `book` or the nested `category`, you should switch `joins` to `includes` - this will preload *all* of the required records and allow you to access their attributes without intensive and inefficient N + 1 queries.

Does that answer your question? Are you having problems with that approach? If you need anything clarifying, let me know and I'll update as needed.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Gomathi, happy to help out - please give this a tick if you feel it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

It is better in rails in my experience to use `includes` as it uses less queries than join which gives better performance- https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

`Order.includes(:categories).where('categories.id = ?', id).references(:categories)`

This really depends on how you like to read whats happening for understanding.

Comment: That's just not true.

Comment: Let me be more specific .. If you would like to to get the information using :joins, it will have to make separate SQL queries for each order it fetches, whereas if you used :include this information is ready for use. Take a watch: http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Comment: Yes I know that. `includes` *doesn't* use less queries than `joins`, as you've stated. In fact, sometimes it'll use more. It's good if you're querying the associated records to avoid any N + 1s, though there's no mention of doing that in the question and this can be at the expense of efficiency. Take a read: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: Yes. You added a good point. While not all cases are efficient I think for this case `includes` will have a better performance as @Gomathi trying to fetch the data and use the information.

Comment: He doesn't say that anywhere.

Comment: The context can be interpreted that way that there are many orders within a category and that is what is being returned.

Comment: It's what's being queried. There's no reason at all to assume the `book` or `category` are needed - they _might_ be, but it's not worth assuming. That means all orders, associated books _and_ categories will be loaded, which is very inefficient if unneeded. Making an assumption like that and giving an unarguably incorrect explanation of why you'd choose between the methods -- as in your answer -- is bad practice.